# Good One --> Riddle: ...You clap for me

Tags: riddle

```
I am something...
When you see me, you always clap for me
yet you hate me, but prefer me to my wife
```

**who am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> a mosquito?

I am something...

> a mosquito is something

When you see me, you always clap for me

> I wanna kill you! I wanna smash you! I wanna make sure you won't survive the clap!

yet you hate me, but prefer me to my wife

> only female mosquito suck blood, male ones are just annoying buzzing creatures

Comment: That last bit applies to humans too

Comment: that's the answer!